# Easily redirect to login in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, satellizer

Is there an easier way to redirect to the `login` state without using a `resolve: {}` on each state?  My app is growing and adding resolves like `loginRequired` or `skipIfLoggedIn` to individual states is cluttering my config blocks.  If it helps, I'm using Satellizer for authentication.

Example module route config:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('uberCoolModule')
        .config(configRoutes);

    configRoutes.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];
    function configRoutes ($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider

            .state('login', {
                url         : '/login',
                templateUrl : 'entrance/login/login.html',
                data        : { pageTitle: 'Login' },
                resolve: {
                    skipIfLoggedIn: skipIfLoggedIn
                }
            })
            .state('logout', {
                url         : '/logout',
                controller  : 'Logout'
                resolve: {
                    loginRequired: loginRequired
                }
            })
            .state('members', {
                url         : '/members',
                controller  : 'Home'
                resolve: {
                    loginRequired: loginRequired
                }
            });

        function skipIfLoggedIn($q, $auth) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if ($auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                deferred.reject();
            } else {
                deferred.resolve();
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        function loginRequired($q, $location, $auth) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if ($auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                deferred.resolve();
            } else {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }

    }

})();
```

Comment: You can bind the `$rootScope` to a [$stateChangeStart](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) event, and check everything there

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is have a parent state that contains the authorization resolve and make all states that require login be children of that parent state.

A child state can not be accessed if resolve of any of it's ancestor states  gets rejected

```
   app.state('members', {
     url: '/members',
     controller: 'Home'
     resolve: {
       loginRequired: loginRequired
     }
   }).state('members.profile', {
     url: '/profile',
   });
```

In this example going to `/members/profile` will fail if `loginRequired` is rejected

Comment: Excellent point.  This app uses nested states with one parent state per module... six modules means only six `resolve` statements.  The only place I'm not using abstract states is in the entrance module (login, logout, etc.).  I feel much better.